# Selenium Webdriver Error regarding destroyHarder

Tags: eclipse, selenium

What kind of error is the below one. This occurs when I execute the webdriver script in eclipse:

> Jun 20, 2014 1:20:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
>   INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@118ed3c

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug. I think you have to downgrade your firefox to 29, if you are using firefox 30.

Please find the below url for moreinformation

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7506

Comment: the article also mentions that one may delete plugin-container.exe (worked for me, i'm using FF 30).  the bug appears to have been closed, hoping that FF 31 fixes this issue for Selenium 2.41+

Comment: whoops, after upgrading to FF 31 it doesn't seem to improve the situation.  i'm opting to go with removing plugin-container.exe

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing this problem in one test project out of four.

Initial investigation led me to conclusion that this happens when trying to quit firefox while page is still loading (the green circle in tab)

If you use Java you can try the following:

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadFinishedCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(pageLoadFinishedCondition);
```

**UPD:**

But be advised that 'document is ready' event happens slightly before firefox stops that green circle, so you may need to idle a bit.

Further investigation showed that this is highly dependent on the application itself (And in my case, did not work) E.g. when being on login page of the application, I could not exit, while being on dashboard everything was just fine.

I suggest you try the following:

1. Downgrade to Firefox <30 (problem persists in 33)
2. Quit while being on another page of the application (invent some stub here)
3. Make `driver.navigate().refresh();` or something like this.
4. Giant idling before quit() sometimes helps, say, 2*implicitlywait

**UPD:**

5. Also, deleting *plugin-container.exe* might help. Note that after I deleted one, flash wasn't loading into my page any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same problem since I upgraded to Firefox.Seems like a plugin compatibility error with Firefox Plugin.I'm not sure if it downgrading will help.

But I removed driver.quit(); from my code as I didn't want the browser to close even after execution of the script.This stopped the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block in your Test annotation.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or you can try this too

```
try{
driver.close();
}
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in After annotation.

It should solve the problem.

Comment: Catching the exception is not solving, that is a workaround. Might be the only option, but still....

Comment: @Mariamj you have one extra bracket in the second sample which makes it uncompilable if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

instead of simply

```
driver.quit();
```

use:

```
driver.close();

try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: When doing this, you suppress an exception from quit() by intention. The exception however arises because there's no more open browser windows. But I'm unsure, if your solution doesn't prevent the logs from being deleted.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, interesting. But it applies to the case that you open only one browser when close() is the same as quit().

```
    driver.close();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //driver.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```